# Multiple filter for an especific table

Tags: javascript

I have this code working for any table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('.CalendarFilter').click(function () {
        var values = [];

         $('.filter').each(function () {
            var colIdx = $(this).data('col');

             $(this).find('option:selected').each(function () {
                 if ($(this).val() != "") values.push( {
                    text: $(this).text(),
                    colId : colIdx
                 });
            });
        });
        filter('table > tbody > tr', values);
    });

    function filter(selector, values) {console.log(values);
        $(selector).each(function () {
            var sel = $(this);
            var tokens = sel.text().trim().split('\n');
            var toknesObj = [], i;
            for(i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
                toknesObj[i] = {
                   text:tokens[i].trim(), 
                   found:false
                };
            }

            var show = false;
            //console.log(toknesObj);
            $.each(values, function (i, val) {                

           if (toknesObj[val.colId].text.search(new RegExp("\\b"+val.text+"\\b")) >= 0) {
               toknesObj[val.colId].found = true;
              }

            });          
            console.log(toknesObj);
            var count = 0;
             $.each(toknesObj, function (i, val) {
                 if (val.found){
                     count+=1;
                 }
             });
            show = (count === values.length);        
            show ? sel.show() : sel.hide();
        });
    }
    });
```

It filters good, the problem I have is with an special table that is not working. I have the ID of the table but I don't know how to implement the code for work exclusively for this table ID. I tried modifying this part `filter('#TABLEID > tbody > tr', values);` but is nor working.

Goal: modify the code to work only with an specific table (specifically one with ID posts-table-1, see jsfiddle below), because the code, which supposedly works for any table, doesn't work

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mdomfu/gzLktpmw/3/

Comment: Please describe the problem in detail. What's the goal? What's not working?

Comment: Goal: modify the code to work only with an specific table (specifically one with ID posts-table-1, see jsfiddle below), because the code, which supposedly works for any table, doesn't work

Comment: Any help here? 